# Accidentally deleted python* files

Tags: python, launcher

I was getting some certificate error doesnt match 'www.python.org'.

so I thought it is mistake of python and removed all file start with python (pyhton*) thus now I am unable to access terminal, not even getting options to close ,minimise options if i open any folder. I cant even see unity launcher also.

can someone help me how to recover python files????

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include as much information as possible about *how* you did this? If you used the terminal, what command or commands did you run? In your home folder there is a file called `.bash_history` that lists your recent commands (usually up to 2000 of them). You can access this file even without being able to use the Terminal. For example, if your graphical file browser works, open your home folder and press Ctrl+H to toggle whether or not hidden entries are shown (files and folders named starting with `.` are hidden by default). You can then open the file in a text editor.

Comment: Reinstall without formatting (only mount your disks during the partitioning part of the install).

Comment: I [really doubt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878623/accidentally-deleted-python-files/878647?noredirect=1#comment1367115_878647) you need to reinstall Ubuntu, though depending on the circumstances that might be a reasonable approach. I verified APT works without Python--at least in 16.04--so you should be able to put it back from a terminal. Even if `gnome-terminal` doesn't work, `xterm` or a virtual console should. *What* packages to install, and the extent of the breakage, depend on how it happened. Except by wild guessing, I don't think this can be answered until you provide details.

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised you can even boot. Python is an integral part of the system that even `ubuntu-minimal` depends upon it. Removing via package manager is not possible. I'm not surprised you can't do things.

Your problem now is that to reinstall these files, you need stuff like package managers to work. But they require Python to be there in some form. You probably could attempt to mirror your install and then copy across all the files you deleted... But between the time that would take, and the other issues you would likely run into along the way, I think it's probably a waste of time. Certainly when the *other option* is so much faster.

It is possible that you've not done as much damage as you claim (that's why it's important to follow the comments under your question and give us as much information about "the event" as possible) but if things are as broken as they seem, you did a pretty good job ☺ and my answer above stands.

The take-away message, here: **Congratulations, you get to reinstall.**

<sub>I'm British so this might come across as snide or condescending but I honestly don't mean it that way. I've broken **dozens** of computers over the years doing stuff just like this. This is how we learn. What you've done is pretty terminal but there's no shame here. You now know not to do it again.</sub>

Comment: *"Removing via package manager is not possible."* That is false--I just tried it. Specifically, on a fully updated virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04 installed from the minimal CD, I installed `openssh-server`, then SSHed in and [ran `sudo apt-get purge 'python*'`, verified neither Python 2 nor Python 3 was installed, and rebooted](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23905237/). It booted successfully, and I was able to successfully SSHed back in. I [ran  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-standard ubuntu-minimal`, which succeeded, and I verified `python3` was installed](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23905262/).

Comment: I get an `E: Unmet dependencies.` error.

Comment: This is incorrect, you do *not* need to reinstall. If you boot a Live CD, this is fixable -- I'll try to write an answer later.

Comment: At least you didn't [`sudo rm -rf /`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4YhFdxrkOw)

Comment: @cat Do you have a way to answer this that doesn't require more information from the OP? I suppose one could give a procedure for checking what packages, if any, were uninstalled, and either installing the appropriate metapackage(s) to restore them and anything else that was unintentionally removed or, if the problem is really deleted files rather than removed packages, *re*installing specific packages that provide those files (such as by running `apt install` with the `--reinstall` option). Do you still want to post an answer? Should we not have closed this question? Should we reopen it?